# How can I do two-way data binding to an Enumerated property without auxiliary code (C# / MVVM)?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, enums, mvvm-light

I have a C# MVVM Light based application with several enumerated properties.  I am tired of writing plumbing code to support them.  Usually the plumbing code I write is in the shape of paired string properties or at other times type specific value converters to facilitate data binding to the enumerated properties.  How can I do this without writing extra code just to bridge data bound UI elements to the enumerated properties?

Answer (score 1):

I did a little digging and experimenting and now I have a value converter for any ViewModel enumerated property that does two-way conversion between the Description attribute strings for the enumerated values and the enumeration constants they represent.  This allows you to do two-way data binds to an enumerated property without having to do any plumbing code.  The only thing you have to do is put the *fully qualified type name* for the Enumeration type of the bound property in the **ConverterParameter** field (see picture below for an example).  If you have trouble determining the correct fully qualified Enum type name, just set a break point in **ConvertBack()** where an Exception will be thrown.  Then call *System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes.ToList()* in the Immediate Window to get a list of all currently defined System types in that execution context.  Find the correct fully qualified type name and paste it into the **ConverterParameter** field.

- Use **ToDescriptionsList<>()** to conveniently grab the Description attributes from an *Enum* type to fill a List Box or other element.  Put the call to it in the property that returns a list of human friendly strings to the UI element bound to the enumerated property.  (For example, the **ItemsSource** property of a list box).

Example of an Enumerated type with Description Attributes:

```
    // (barnyard, bird, cat, dog, horse, pig, reptile, smallfurry)
    // List of Animal types the breed list method accepts.
    public enum EnumAnimalType
    {
        [Description("Barnyard")]
        barnyard,
        [Description("Birds")]
        bird,
        [Description("Cats & Kittens")]
        cat,
        [Description("Dogs & Puppies")]
        dog,
        [Description("Horses & Ponies")]
        horse,
        [Description("Pigs")]
        pig,
        [Description("Reptiles")]
        reptile,
        [Description("Other Small & Furry")]
        smallfurry
    }
```

[image: Sample Value Converter declaration during data binding]

```
// Value converter class that does the conversion work.
public class EnumToDescAttrConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // Derived Grant Barrintgon's blog on C#.

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method that retrieves the description attribute for a particular enum value.
    /// [Description("Bright Pink")]
    /// BrightPink = 2,
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="en">The Enumeration</param>
    /// <returns>A string representing the friendly name</returns>
    public string GetDescription(Enum en)
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();

        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
        }

        // Unable to find a description attribute for the enum.  Just return the
        //  value of the ToString() method.
        return en.ToString();
    }

    // Consumer wants to convert an enum to a description attribute string.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Since we don't know what the correct default value should be, a NULL value is unacceptable.
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("(EnumToDescAttrConverter:Convert) The value is unassigned.");

        Enum e = (Enum)value;

        return e.GetDescription();
    } // public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

    // Convert an enumeration value in Description attribute form back to the appropriate enum value.
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Since we don't know what the correct default value should be, a NULL value is unacceptable.
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("(EnumToDescAttrConverter:ConvertBack) The value is unassigned.");

        string strValue = (string)value;

        // Parameter parameter must be set since it must contain the concrete Enum class name.
        if (parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("(EnumToDescAttrConverter:ConvertBack) The Parameter parameter is unassigned.");

        string theEnumClassName = parameter.ToString();

        // Create an instance of the concrete enumeration class from the given class name.
        Enum e = (Enum)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(theEnumClassName);

        if (e == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "(EnumToDescAttrConverter:ConvertBack) Invalid enumeration class name: " + theEnumClassName
                + ". Set a break point here and call System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes.ToList()"
                + " in the immediate window to find the right type.  Put that type into the Converter parameter for the"
                + " data bound element you are working with."
                );

        System.Type theEnumType = e.GetType();

        Enum eRet = null;

        foreach (MemberInfo memInfo in theEnumType.GetMembers())
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                if (((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description == strValue)
                {
                    // Ignore the case
                    eRet = (Enum)Enum.Parse(theEnumType, memInfo.Name, true);
                    break; // Found it.
                }
            }
        } // foreach (MemberInfo memInfo in typeof(TEnum).GetMembers())

        // If the string can not be converted to a valid enum value, throw an
        //  Exception.
        if (eRet == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} can not be converted to an enum value: ", strValue));

        return eRet;
    } // public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

    /// <summary>
    ///  Returns all the values for given Enum as a list of their string attributes.  <br />
    ///   Use this method to fill a list box with human friendly strings for each <br />
    ///   enumeration value using the DescriptionAttribute() associated it/them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns>An enumerator for the Enum values</returns>
    public static List<string> ToDescriptionsList<T>()
    {
        // GetValues() is not available on Windows Phone.
        // return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
        List<string> listRet = new List<string>();

        foreach (var x in typeof(T).GetFields())
        {
            Enum e;

            if (x.IsLiteral)
            {
                e = (Enum)x.GetValue(typeof(Enum));

                listRet.Add(e.GetDescription());
            } // if (x.IsLiteral)
        } // foreach()

        return listRet;
    } // public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>(this T theEnum)    } // public class EnumToDescAttrConverter : IValueConverter
} // public class EnumToDescAttrConverter : IValueConverter
```

Comment: @LaurentBugnion - I'd like your opinion on this since your MVVM Light framework inspired me to do this.